# MySQL server hangs after executing a simple query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, server

I have a MySQL server running on ARM machine and I have a query which is run in `phpmyadmin` through web interface (or php on website)

```
select * from some_table where id IN (select id from other_table)
```

**This simple query will result in MySQL service hanging until restart.**
What is the reason?

In other words:

if I manually enter id's - be it 1 or 100 - it will not fail:

```
select * from some_table where id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....120)
```

on the other hand - if ids are generated from inner query, then service will hang:

```
select * from some_table where id IN (select id from other_table)
```

I have full access to server and it is possible to reconfigure it as necessary. How can I solve the issue?

**Database server**

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket

Server type: MySQL

Server version: 5.5.35-1ubuntu1 - (Ubuntu)

Protocol version: 10

User: root@localhost

Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**Web server**

```
nginx/1.4.6

Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.35

PHP extension: mysqli
```

**phpMyAdmin**

```
Version information: 4.0.10deb1
```

P.S. what I mean by hanging is that `mysql` becomes unresponsive. Command `top` will show that MySQL service is eating up all cores. Restart done by command `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`.

P.P.S. full query that hangs. fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84fe8/1

```
select
    goo.t1_score,
    goo.t2_score,
    gr.t1_score,
    gr.t2_score,
    gr.unique_key
from games_ongoing goo, game_results gr
where
goo.id in (
        select max(id)
        from games_ongoing
        group by unique_key
        having count(id) >= 3 and MIN(t1_score) = MIN(t2_score) and MIN(t1_score) = 0
        )
and gr.unique_key = goo.unique_key
```

Comment: You are using subquery thats why

Comment: Why are you doing this? What's wrong with JOIN?

Comment: what's wrong with using subquery? I do it all day long in oracle

Comment: @Strawberry In full subquery I am also using an GROUP BY statement. Is it even possible to convert it to JOINs ?

Comment: Your query doesn't quite make sense (unless, perhaps, there is a 1-1 correlation between the two tables, but then MAX would make no sense).Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Does your subquery itself work? And aren't you missing a join in your P.P.P.S.?

Comment: @Strawberry yes subquery worked but main part had errors (draft version, sorry) . I have created a working fiddle. Please have a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb264/11

Comment: if you come up with issues like this you could always look at your mysql, nginx and php logs to give you an idea about things.

Comment: The subquery is irrelevant, but it would have been helpful if you had provided some stats for the tables, the index structure, the engine type and the EXPLAIN plan.

Comment: @symcbean it's there (see schema): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84fe8/1

Comment: This does not include the data metrics (partially exposed in the output of EXPLAIN) which inform the optimizer choices and are a key determinant of query performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your original question. In MySQL, this query:

```
select * from some_table where id IN (select id from other_table)
```

would execute the following query:

```
SELECT  id
FROM    other_table
WHERE   other_table.id = some_table.id
```

for each record in `some_table`, while this one:

```
select * from some_table where id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....120)
```

will seek each value from the list in `some_table`. If there are lots of records on `some_table` but few in `other_table`, you should rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT  st.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                id
        FROM    other_table
        ) ot
JOIN    some_table st
ON      st.id = ot.id
```

which will search each distinct `other_table.id` in the index on `some_table.id`.

Now, assuming there can be no negative score, you should run this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    game_results gr
JOIN    games_ongoing goo
ON      goo.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    games_ongoing goi
        WHERE   goi.unique_key = gr.unique_key
                AND EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    games_ongoing goz
                WHERE   goz.unique_key = goi.unique_key
                        AND (goz.t1_score, goz.t2_score) = (0, 0)
                )
                AND EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    games_ongoing goc
                WHERE   goc.unique_key = goi.unique_key
                LIMIT   2, 1
                )
        ORDER BY
                goi.unique_key DESC, goi.id DESC
        LIMIT   1
        )
```

Create the following indexes for the query to work fast:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_game_results_unique_key ON game_results (unique_key);
CREATE INDEX ix_games_ongoing_unique_key ON games_ongoing (unique_key);
CREATE INDEX ix_games_ongoing_unique_key_t2_score_t2_score ON games_ongoing (unique_key, t1_score, t2_score);
```

See the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72444/1

Comment: thank you for the explanation! I haven't tried adding indexes, but without them - server hangs as usual.. I will try adding indexes later, possibly solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, to recap... here's an intermediate result

```
SELECT o.id o_id
     , o.t1_score o_t1_score
     , o.t2_score o_t2_score
     , r.t1_score r_t1_score
     , r.t2_score r_t2_score
     , r.unique_key
  FROM games_ongoing o
  JOIN game_results r
    ON r.unique_key = o.unique_key;
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| o_id | o_t1_score | o_t2_score | r_t1_score | r_t2_score | unique_key |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    1 |          0 |          0 |          1 |          3 | 111        |
|    2 |          0 |          1 |          1 |          3 | 111        |
|    3 |          0 |          2 |          1 |          3 | 111        |
|    4 |          1 |          2 |          1 |          3 | 111        |
|    5 |          1 |          2 |          1 |          3 | 111        |
|    6 |          0 |          0 |          5 |          4 | 222        |
|    7 |          1 |          1 |          5 |          4 | 222        |
|    8 |          2 |          1 |          5 |          4 | 222        |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

In order to get the unique keys with the highest (ongoing) ids, we can use an uncorrelated subquery, like this:

```
 SELECT x.*
      , r.*
   FROM games_ongoing x
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT unique_key, MAX(id) max_id FROM games_ongoing GROUP BY unique_key ) y
     ON y.unique_key = x.unique_key
    AND y.max_id = x.id
   JOIN game_results r
     ON r.unique_key = x.unique_key;

+----+---------+---------+------------+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+------------+
| id | t1_name | t2_name | unique_key | t1_score | t2_score | id | t1_score | t2_score | unique_key |
+----+---------+---------+------------+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+------------+
|  5 | team1   | team2   | 111        |        1 |        2 |  1 |        1 |        3 | 111        |
|  8 | team3   | team4   | 222        |        2 |        1 |  2 |        5 |        4 | 222        |
+----+---------+---------+------------+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+------------+
```

This should perform considerably better than the query above, but for further help optimizing this, we would need to see the EXPLAIN.

Comment: in this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31333/1 I need ids 5 and 8. I.e.: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31333/2